# Prevent block variation inside certain parent blocks

Tags: block-editor

Is there a way of preventing the use of a  certain block variation inside a specific parent block?

I have an "inner blocks" block that is basically a group block but without any settings, it's just a container for inner blocks. I have another block that is almost the same thing except it has one attribute. I would like to just use the first block, and add the second as a variation, but only allow the variation to be used inside one specific parent block.

Is this doable?